# C++ - Invalid Conversion from 'void*' to 'uint8_t**'

Tags: c++

I have a beginner question and I don't found any right way.
In the header I had:

```
    static uint8_t **data = NULL;
```

and in my function then I want to:

```
    data = av_mallocz (sizeof (uint8_t*) *planes);
```

But here comes the error:

> A Invalid Conversion from 'void*' to 'uint8_t**'

The `av_mallocz` function come from ffmpeg: `return av_mallocz (nmemb *size);`

Anyone an idea?

Comment: In `C` you can implicitly cast from `void*` to any other pointer type. In `C++`, you can't. You have to cast explicitly.

Comment: @BoBTFish - in C there is an **implicit conversion** from `void*` to any other pointer type. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion, that is, it's an **explicit conversion**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = (uint8_t**)av_mallocz (sizeof (uint8_t*) *planes);
```

Remember, the `sizeof (uint8_t*)` doesnt tell your code what type the data is going to be, it just helps calculate for the malloc how much space it needs. The malloc return generic space, which is why is uses void*. You still need to cast that void* to the type you want.
Oh, and since this is C++, you might want to consider a `static_cast<uint8_t**>(...)`, just to be nicer.

Comment: I forgot the second pointer after the first uint8_t, thanks it worked now. I accept ur answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @user2492388 Very good idea. There's a link on the right 'The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List'. Amazing how many people want to learn C++ from youtube videos.